# SQL Sumif statement request

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to create a column that will get the total hours based on the store column and the hours column. See below table.  So it will total up rep1,2,3 from store 142 and total rep 1,2 from store 356. Then I would also like to devide hours into total to get a contribution% column

```
   Date store rep hours total cont%
    --------------------------------------------------
    x   142  rep1   5    11   0.45
    x   142  rep2   2    11   0.18
    x   142  rep3   4    11   0.36
    x   356  rep1   4     7    0.57
    x   356  rep2   3     7    0.42
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want window functions:

```
select t.*, sum(hours) over (partition by store) as total,
       t.hours * 1.0 / sum(hours) over (partition by store) as cont_percent
from t;
```

Comment: Awesome! Wow that was quick. How about the 2nd portion with the contribution% You originally answered before I finished the edit! Thanks again!